# How to find maximum peak location, index with scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing

I want to find the location of the maximum peak how can I do it?
I am using scipy.signal for finding peaks. I want the code to return the location (in ums) for the peak.

[image]

Comment: if your data is stored in a numpy array, just use `np.argmax`. Eg:  `data = np.array([1,2,6,3,2])`  `np.argmax(data)  ->  2`  (which is the location of the maximum element: 6)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to find the highest of the peaks identified by `scipy.signal.find_peaks` then you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import find_peaks
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example data
x = np.linspace(-4000, 4000)  # equal spacing needed for find_peaks
y = np.sin(x / 1000) + 0.1 * np.random.rand(*x.shape)

# Find peaks
i_peaks, _ = find_peaks(y)

# Find the index from the maximum peak
i_max_peak = i_peaks[np.argmax(y[i_peaks])]

# Find the x value from that index
x_max = x[i_max_peak]

# Plot the figure
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.plot(x[i_peaks], y[i_peaks], 'x')
plt.axvline(x=x_max, ls='--', color="k")
plt.show()
```

[image]

If you just want the highest point then do just use argmax as Sembei suggests.